# how to Display div in sequential?

Tags: html, css

Hi guys i'm stuck at this. 
I have a div but when i creating that same div class it will displayed in the next line. But i wanted to appear the second div next to first div. Can any one suggest one best answer.The code is:

```
     <html>
     <head>
     <style>
     .box3{
     margin: 20px auto;
     width: 300px;
     min-height: 310px;
      padding: 10px;
      position:relative;
     background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 20%, 0% 92%, from(#fff), to(#fff), color-stop(.1,#fff));
     border: 1px solid #ccc;
     -webkit-border-radius: 60px 5px;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
     }
     .box3:before{
     content: '';
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
     top:0; right:0;
      position:absolute;
      display: inline-block;
     z-index:-1;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px -10px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
     -webkit-transform: rotate(2deg)
                    translate(-14px,20px)
                       skew(-20deg);
     }

    .box3:after{
    content: '';
       width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
     top:0; left:0;
      position:absolute;
     z-index:-1;
      display: inline-block;
     -webkit-box-shadow: -10px -10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      -webkit-transform: rotate(2deg)
                    translate(20px,25px)
                       skew(20deg);
     }
     .box3 img {
     width: 100%;
      margin-top: 15px;
     }
     p{ 
     margin-top: 15px;
     text-align: justify;
     }
    h1{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 5px; 
     text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    }
    a{
     text-decoration: none;
     color: #4A4A4A !important;
    }
    a:hover{
     text-decoration: underline;
     color: #6B6B6B !important ;
    }
   </style>
   </head>
   <body>
    <div>
    <div class="box3">
   <h1>Sample Box</h1>   
   <img src="http://www.wpthemegenerator.com/wp-  content/uploads/2012/06/Image.jpg">
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam luctus consectetur dolor a porttitor. Curabitur id sem sed ante fringilla pulvinar et id lectus. Nullam justo ipsum, hendrerit ut commodo nec, pellentesque nec erat. Pellentesque pharetra.
   </p> 
   <br />
   <a href="http://www.designshock.com/"> DesignShock.com </a>
   </div>
   <div class="box3">
   <h1>Sample Box</h1>   
   <img src="http://www.wpthemegenerator.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Image.jpg">
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam luctus consectetur dolor a porttitor. Curabitur id sem sed ante fringilla pulvinar et id lectus. Nullam justo ipsum, hendrerit ut commodo nec, pellentesque nec erat. Pellentesque pharetra.
   </p> 
   <br />
   <a href="http://www.designshock.com/"> DesignShock.com </a>
   </div>
   </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: do you mean that: https://jsfiddle.net/sebastianbrosch/xa27czzL/

Comment: Yes. But using float ="left" attribute my website design didn't catch up with it. Can you suggest another method????

Comment: is your website design public? the code is working for me but it seems your website design is working different like the example.

Comment: my project isn't public. The code is working me also. can you suggest another solution to fix this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ok i find a additional solution - see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a two different solutions using float or flexbox.

**Solution #1 (float)**

Add `float:left;` to the class `.box3` - see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sebastianbrosch/xa27czzL/

**Solution #2 (flexbox)**

Add a new class to the surrounding div of the boxes like `.container` and add a new stylesheet for this container with the property `display:flex;`

```
.container {
    display:flex;
}
```

See an example on the following fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sebastianbrosch/xa27czzL/1/

More information about using flexbox you can find here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/